# How to send a json string in a json request?

Tags: json

I need to send a json string in the json request and pass it on the backend to be unmarshalled as an object. ie a JSon request has a string attribute which can be converted to an object later. What's the format for that?

I tried `{"name":"bob","address":{"state":"ny","city":"newport"}}`. I dont want `"address" : {...}` to be unmarshalled here.. i want it to be sent as it is to backend as a String.

FWIW, i m using jackson , and I dont think that should matter.

Also, I dont want to escape the characters ie
 `"address":{\"state\":\"ny\",\"city\":\"newport\"}`

Comment: did you try to `jsonencode` the `json` string to see what happened?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: This doesnt works? 
{"name":"bob","address":"{'state':'ny','city':'newport'}"}

Comment: No, the problem with that is it tries to marshall {"state":.....} into an object instead of marshalling it into String.(the target object has String "jsonString" property.

Comment: Maybe could be idiot, but try this way:
{"name":"bob","address":'{"state":"ny","city":"newport"}'}

Comment: @voodoo this is not a JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to manually encode json yourself, Use an appropriate Json encoder for whatever language you're using.

`{"name":"bob","address":{"state":"ny","city":"newport"}}` is not valid json. the entire string should be quoted. like:

`"{\"name\":\"bob\",\"address\":{\"state\":\"ny\",\"city\":\"newport\"}}"`

and it will arrive at the backend as a string. thats what a json string is, a string.

you need to decode it server side with an appropriate json decoder

if you dont want to escape the quotes then use a combination of single and double quotes like:

`'{"name":"bob","address":{"state":"ny","city":"newport"}}'`

Comment: Yes that works, I have tried that infact, but for whatever reason, I can't use the escape characters. Is there any other way, instead of using escape chars. Thanks! If I dont get any other answer, I will mark this as the right answer as this is correct, but m requirement is a little different.

Comment: only wrapping in single quoutes as suggested

Comment: No single quotes just blows up saying incorrect json. I ended up sending as {"name":"bob","address":{"state":"ny","city":"newport"}} which ended up marshalling address as a map which is available at the backend to simply do a get on the keys state and city. Apparently, jackson simply converts unknown objects to map. In the marshalled class I have the address attribute as Object (could chose it to be a map too). Thanks!

Comment: Choosing this as the right answer as encoding is the right way to do it if you want to send the string as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using php:

```
<?php
$a = json_encode(array("state"=>"NY", "city"=> "Newport"));
$b = array("name"=>bob, "address"=>$a);
print_r($a);
print "\n";
print_r(json_encode($b));
print "\n";
?>
```

Output

```
{"state":"NY","city":"Newport"}
{"name":"bob","address":"{\"state\":\"NY\",\"city\":\"Newport\"}"}
```

The last line is your answer - but making the code do it for you is always preferable.